# Do i need a visa for Dubai if I were to travel to the airport and return without leaving the airport

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, dubai, uae, dxb

My wife will be coming from the US to India via Dubai. I shall be traveling from Chennai, India, to meet her at Dubai and escort her back to Chennai. I will be traveling via Air Emirates [terminal 3]. I will be staying at the airport for around 20 hours with no baggage, do I need a visa or transit visa in order to wait at the airport for her?

Comment: What is your citizenship?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please do not use all-caps; it is considered the equivalent of SHOUTING on the Internet, and in any case more difficult to read. You may find the answer to your question in *[Do I need a transit visa for a layover via Dubai International Airport?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62511/)*

Comment: @Chooster - Technically this is not a transit - Dubai is his destination. Thus that other answer isn't relevant.  It is very likely the airline would not allow him to board, although I don't know the official answer.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You could as well receive your wife in Madras.

Comment: because this is her first trip and she is not very comfortable with English

Comment: I don't understand. If her English is good enough for her to visit the USA, it's surely good enough to get her through Dubai airport. If she's transiting, she might not need to speak to any officials anyway: only the staff of the airline when boarding her new flight.

Answer (score 4):

In most cases, transit without visa is only valid if you are transiting through the country en route to a third country; it is not valid if returning to the country where the journey originated.

[Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=IN&DE=IN&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=00&TR=AE&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX) will warn the airline check-in staff of this:

> Transit Without Visa (TWOV): Passing through an international transit area of the airport in order to board a connecting (or to proceed by the same) flight, without entering the country (i.e. clearing immigration).
>
> Unless stated otherwise, passengers wishing to TWOV must:
>
> - be en-route to a third country (e.g. itinerary TYO-LON-TYO is not considered TWOV);

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you hold an Indian passport and that the passport is valid for at least 6 months from when you arrive in Dubai. Because you are arriving in Dubai and then leaving from Dubai, your final destination is Dubai, therefore you are not transiting.

You will need a visa in order to board the airplane. Emirates will not allow you to board if you [do not obtain a visa in advance](https://www.emirates.com/us/english/plan_book/find_visa_requirements/visa_passport_information_results.aspx?NC=IN&NV=India&DC=AE&DV=United%20Arab%20Emirates&h=5d9a5df925d0cb84fa52a2c3c20609127281eb6).

Luckily:

> Nationals of countries requiring a prearranged UAE visa can now apply
>   and pay for their visas online through [emirates.com](https://www.emirates.com/us/english/plan_book/essential_information/visa_passport_information/uae_visas.aspx).