# Do I need a transit visa for Dubai? (changing airports DWC to DXB)

Tags: visas, transit, dubai, dxb, dwc

My flight is Delhi to Almakhtom when I arrive in Almakhtom I have to change my airport I have to go Dubai international airport.Do I need to a transit Visa dubai

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do I need a transit visa for a layover in the United Arab Emirates?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62511/do-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-a-layover-in-the-united-arab-emirates)

Comment: @ReddHerring The linked Q&A doesn't cover the case of changing airports in Dubai (probably because DWC wasn't yet open when it was written). It should, but currently it does not. And the 96-hour visa on arrival is only available at DXB as far as I can tell.

Comment: Which Visa do you have?

Answer (score 1):

You need a visa for UAE in order to change *airports*.

Because your initial flight lands at DWC, and your connecting flight departs fromm DXB, you must clear immigration at DWC, take ground transportation to DXB, and exit immigration at DXB to reach your connecting flight.

Contact your airline for help with obtaining the UAE transit visa. These can be obtained directly from many airlines which fly to UAE.