# dubai at night with layover

Tags: transit, layovers, dubai, south-african-citizens

Good Day  We are South Africans and will be travelling to Phuket on Emirates airlines with a 9 hour layover. Arriving in Dubai at 00:35. We want to explore Dubai at night for a few hours before our outbound flight. Do we need to book accommodation and is the visa free or the few hours?

Comment: Is this a single ticket, or booked as two separate legs? Where in particular do you want to visit and how do you plan to get there? Entry Immigration waits can be lengthy (as can the queue for non pre-booked taxis), realistically to err on the safe side you don’t have much more than say 5 hours max assuming your inbound flight is on time. Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62511/do-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-a-layover-in-the-united-arab-emirates

Comment: Also worth noting is that many of the top tourist attractions close around 11pm, and wandering around late at night may not be safe in some areas. See eg https://traveltriangle.com/blog/places-to-visit-in-dubai-at-night/ (no affiliation, a quick google search will throw up others).

Comment: Thank you so much, will check Traveltriangle.com