# Does a Fijian need a transit visa for layover in Dubai?

Tags: transit-visas, layovers, dubai, dxb, fijian-citizens

I am traveling from Madrid, Spain to Brisbane, Australia with Emirates Airline with a 3 hour transit in Dubai. I am on a Fiji passport and wanted to know if a transit visa will be required for Dubai for this short layover. I do not plan on leaving the airport.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Do I need a transit visa for a layover in the United Arab Emirates?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62511/do-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-a-layover-in-the-united-arab-emirates) you don't need a visa if you're staying airside.

If you want to leave the airport you need to get a visa as a Fijian citizen.