# Do I, a Ghana citizen, need a transit visa for transferring between flights at Dubai International Airport?

Tags: transit, transit-visas, uae, dxb, ghanaian-citizens

I’m a citizen of Ghana, and I will be landing at Dubai International Airport, where I will need to switch airlines. Do I have to get a transit visa?

Comment: How long are you staying in Dubai and where is your final destination?

Comment: Of related interest: *[Do I need a transit visa for a layover in the United Arab Emirates?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62511)*