# Reliable options to travel back to Philippines from Chennai, India

Tags: transit-visas, filipino-citizens, uae, dxb

I am currently in Chennai for a 1 week business trip. Yesterday was supposed to be my flight back to Manila (I am a Philippine passport holder). My Itinerary was:

> (Indigo)Chennai -> Bangalore -> Dubai (Gulf Air) -> Bahrain -> Manila

However when getting my boarding pass, they said I cannot go because I am not holding Transit Visa for Dubai. Said it is their protocol and they also confirmed with their counterpart in Dubai.
I have all the booking details, negative PCR test result, no luggage. Now I am back in the hotel planning how to get back to PH.

Question now is:

1. When booking for my next flight, which countries can I select for connecting flights which will not require transit visa?
2. If I book with Emirates and supposed they can help me with getting the transit visa, how long will the processing take?

Additional info:
I booked this roundtrip flights with http://www.supertravel.se/. When going to India, I also had connecting flight through Dubai and I also don't have transit visa at the time but I was able to move from Terminal 3 to Terminal 2. I read that having no luggage, you don't need to go through immigration.

Comment: Related https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62511/do-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-a-layover-in-the-united-arab-emirates but not duplicate. The comments in accepted answer say T3/2 connection is problematic. Probably why youbwere refused boarding.

Comment: So just to clarify, you are flying Indigo up to Dubai and then changing to Gulf Air for the remaining flights?  If so, this is likely the problem, because you need a transit visa for this.  If you can find a single-ticket/airline connection you would likely be OK.

Comment: Yes. I should have selected a single airline. Another information I got when I messaged Emirates just now is that "they don't allow transit passengers from India to Dubai until Feb 28. They only allow passengers whose final destination is Dubai".